# Why simple_html_dom isnt getting div content for specific pages but its working for other pages on same site

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

i am trying to get `plaintext title` from `<div id="title"></div>` tag from this url

```
https://thepiratebay.gd/torrent/12745130/
```

i am using php like this

```
<?php 
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$torrent_page_url = 'https://thepiratebay.gd/torrent/12745130/';

$html = file_get_html($torrent_page_url);

$title = $html->find('div[id=title]', 0)->plaintext ;

echo ( $title);
?>
```

this gives me

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in file.php on line 8
```

when i check the source of the url it shows

```
<div id="title">
        WWE Table For 3 S01E10 Kings Court 720p WEBRip h264-WD -={SPARRO</div>
```

if i change url from

```
$torrent_page_url = 'https://thepiratebay.gd/torrent/12745130/';
```

to any other url one same site having same structure e.g. pages

```
$torrent_page_url = 'https://thepiratebay.gd/torrent/12829104/';
$torrent_page_url = https://thepiratebay.gd/torrent/12745118/';
```

i get proper output.

e.g.

```
Jugaadi Dot Com (2015) DvDRip x264 AC3 [DDR]
```

and url source shows

```
<div id="title">
        Jugaadi Dot Com (2015) DvDRip x264 AC3 [DDR]</div>
```

so why my code isnt working for some pages while its working fine for other pages ? even though all of these pages having same markup/html source.

what i am missing ?

simple_html_dom http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It seems to be a bug. If you switch [to this](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom) it will work.

Comment: @pguardiario thanks, its working as expected, but is it better than , using regex to find specific div and then parsing that div html content using str_get_html using simple_html_dom and then use find to get content inside the div ?

Comment: Yes, it's way better.